# Session don't behave in the same way even if php.ini is almost identical

Tags: session, php

I have a development local server (WAMP) and a remote one (LAMP): even if I have two almost identical php.ini session configurations, it happens that session expires after 24 minutes of inactivity on remote server (this is 'cause of session.gc_maxlifetime configuration) and... never on local server

Well, I'd expect at least the same behavior in both servers, but it ain't so (ideally I'd like on remote server the same "don't expire 'til browser is closed" behavior that I have on local)... apart from session "zone" in php.ini what should I check to make them behave in the same way?

Here are two screenshots:

Local: http://www.ivanhalen.com/phpini/local.png

Remote: http://www.ivanhalen.com/phpini/remote.png

Thanks in advance for the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, at least we can say the remote server does what you asked him to do.
Your problem is on the wamp server, your sessions should expires after 24 minutes. theres certainly something wrong on your wamp installation.

This can be as well because your local wamp installation does not get enough requests. Garbage Collection is done with a probability factor (gc_probability/gc_divisor). So if you do not run a lot of requests on you wamp installation chances are that this 1% is never hit, and no garbage collection of the sessions occurs.

And if you want a long session, then increase the gc_maxlifetime setting, but be carefull, with high trffic this can make a lot of unused session files on your server.

Comment: Yes, I guess that's becaouse I don't do much requests to my local web server (while the remote server is a shared one, with - I guess - thousand of requests).